# Modify textblock of a UserControl from another UserControl WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

i have a `UserControl` that contains a `TextBox` now i am loading another `UserControl` that contains a `TextBlock` .When the button is clicked, I want to assign value entered in `TextBox` to `TextBlock` of another control that is loaded. How can i do this ?

**Main UserControl**

```
<UserControl x:Class="IntelliVentory.UserControls.CategoryControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="670" d:DesignWidth="1100">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>  
        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Name="CategoryNameBox" Width="350" />
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Click="AddCategoryFunc">Load Another Control</Button>
        <Grid Grid.Row="2" Name="CategoriesWraper"></Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**Another UserControl**

```
<UserControl x:Class="IntelliVentory.UserControlModules.CategoryModule"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:IntelliVentory.UserControlModules"
         xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Name="CategoryName" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Thin">Category Name Here</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**Main UserControl.cs**
Loading another UserControl.

```
private void AddCategoryFunc(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    UserControl categoryMod = new CategoryModule();
    CategoriesWraper.Children.Add(categoryMod);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to have something like

```
categoryMod.CategoryNameValue = categoryControl.CategoryNameValue;
```

So you need to define two properties, one `CategoryNameValue` property with which you **get** the Text value of the TextBox, and one `CategoryNameValue` property with which you can **set** the Text property of the TextBlock.

Define this property in the `CategoryControl` class,

```
public string CategoryNameValue { get { return CategoryNameBox.Text; }
```

And this in CategoryModule class,

```
public string CategoryNameValue { set { CategoryName.Text = value; }
```

And you can start using them in your code.

You can define them as [Dependency Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-properties-overview) instead of plain CLR properties, and then look to use [data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-binding-wpf). With data binding both user controls can be bound to the same data model so their values are synced automatically.

**Edit:**

Turns out you can access a UserControl's child elements from outside as if they are public fields. That is, you can write code like this without having to define new properties

```
CategoryModule categoryMod = new CategoryModule();
categoryMod.CategoryName.Text = CategoryNameBox.Text; 
CategoriesWraper.Children.Add(categoryMod);
```

Comment: hi ! simple above solution doesn't work ! can you please update your answer with dependency properties ? will be thankful !

Comment: @hammas_Stack what is the symptom of not work? Are the get/set being called at all?

Comment: no ! it says that UserControl doesn't contain a definition for `CategoryName` in this line `CategoryMod.CategoryName`

Comment: `            //((CategoryModule)categoryMod).CategoryName.Text= CategoryNameNew;
            ((CategoryModule)categoryMod).CategoryNameNew = CategoryNameNew;`

Comment: casting like this work directly and through property ! update the answer sir and i will mark it as answer !

Comment: @hammas_Stack thanks for the offer. I will update my answer once I get my laptop to run the code.

Comment: @hammas_Stack See my updated answer. You declared `categoryMod` as
 type `UserControl` so you need the casting `(CategoryModule)categoryMod`, which is unnecessary if you declared it as  type `CategoryModule`, compare my code and yours you will see the difference.